# Import / read variable from separate gulp file

Tags: javascript, gulp, fs

I'm looking to split my gulpfile.js `assets` or `src` variables into separate files so that I can manage them better. For example:

```
....

var scripts = ['awful.js', 'lot.js', 'of.js', 'js.js', 'files.js']

....(somewhere down the line)

gulp.task('vendorjs', function() {
    return gulp.src(scripts)

        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.root + 'dist'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'vendorjs task completed' }));
});
```

So what I'm basically interested if theres a way to actually move to a separate file the `scripts` variable and be able to access it from `gulpfile.js`.

I've been looking into something like:

```
require("fs").readFile('gulp/test.js', function(e, data) {
   //(test.js would be the file that holds the scripts var)
});
```

Howerver while it does read the contents of the file, I still can't access it from the `gulpfile.js`. Any tips or ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Node.js allows you to import other files using `require()`. It supports [three types of files](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together):

- JSON files. See [DavidDomain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762127/5892036) for that.
- Binary Node.js addons. Not useful for your use case.
- JavaScript files. That's what you want.

For JavaScript files the value returned from `require()` is the one that is assigned to  [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) in the imported file.

So for your use case:

**gulp/test.js**

```
var arrayOfFiles = ["awful.js", "lots.js"];
arrayOfFiles.push("of.js");
arrayOfFiles.push("js.js");
arrayOfFiles.push("files.js");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arrayOfFiles.push("some_other_file" + i + ".js");       
}

module.exports = {
  scripts: arrayOfFiles
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var test = require('gulp/test.js');

gulp.task('vendorjs', function() {
  return gulp.src(test.scripts)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.root + 'dist'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'vendorjs task completed' }));
});
```

Comment: Sounds about right, tested it out and worked a-ok. Thanks! (in 20 hours bounty will be sent :) )

Answer (score 4):

You could use a json file to store your assets or source file location in and load that into your gulp file.

For example:

```
// config.json

{
  "scripts": ["awful.js", "lot.js", "of.js", "js.js", "files.js"]
}
```

And in your gulp file you would do

```
// gulpfile.js

var config = require('./config');

var scripts = config.scripts;

console.log(scripts);
```

Comment: the thing is that the file would be more complex than that, more like an `object` like: `var scripts = { main: [ 'some-script ], notmain: ['etc'] }`. I'm gonna give a shot though, and see how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: JSON derives from JavaScript so you should be able to build pretty complex structures that can be parsed to an object that fits your needs. As long as you use valid json syntax.

Comment: well yeah, however I'm goinn for a more 'dynamic' approach on that file, so thats why I was a asking for a `.js` file; like maybe passing a `for loop` and build the final output 'dynamically' - not sure if thats a word and/or the right word :D

Comment: your approach works alright, is there any way to do that with a `.js` file? like access the output like in your example?

Comment: I am sure you could use your own module and require it into your gulpfile.